# Facing problems while trying to use foreman with R10k on puppet master

Tags: rubygems, open-source, puppet, foreman, r10k

I tried installing puppet with foreman using foreman installer. It uses ruby version 2.0 and after that i installed r10k which requires ruby version >2.3. So i updated ruby using gems after which my foreman stopped working. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Which OS and which versions of puppet and foreman?

Comment: Older versions of puppet in packages managers probably are using older versions of ruby (like puppet3).  Puppet4-6 come installed under /opt/puppet{,labs}/ and are bundled with their own version of ruby.  You may need to install an older version of the r10k gem if you need to use that particular version of puppet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install r10k using the puppet module available on puppet forge.

You can also bypass the current version of ruby & set it to Ruby version 2.3 for the current working shell using the below command

```
scl enable rh-ruby23 bash
```

Comment: This only works for a current shell. To permanently fix it need to change the system ruby.